# Project Euler "Largest prime factor" (#3) in Java

Tags: java, project-euler, primes, java-8

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

I wrote the following code with help of some Java 8, I'll explain the equivalent to Java 7 under the code. I'd like general comments. One note to give up ahead is that I did not write a program that gives the largest prime factor, but one that gives all prime factors.

```
public class ProjectEuler {
    private final static int WARMUP_COUNT = 0;
    private final static int REAL_COUNT = 1;

    private final List<Problem<?>> problems = new ArrayList<>();

    private void init() {
        problems.add(new Problem1());
        problems.add(new Problem2());
        problems.add(new Problem3(600851475143L));

        process();
    }

    private void process() {
        problems.stream().forEachOrdered(new ProblemConsumer());
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProjectEuler().init();
    }

    private class ProblemConsumer implements Consumer<Problem<?>> {
        @Override
        public void accept(Problem<?> problem) {            
            for (int i = 0; i < WARMUP_COUNT; i++) {
                problem.run();
            }
            System.gc();

            long start = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < REAL_COUNT; i++) {
                problem.run();
            }
            double average = (System.nanoTime() - start) * 1.0d / REAL_COUNT;

            String result = problem.getResult();

            System.out.println(problem.getName() + ": " + result + " (" + String.format("%.5f", (average / 1_000_000.0)) + " ms" + ")");
        }        
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Problem3 extends Problem<List<Long>> {
    private final long number;

    public Problem3(final long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long numberCopy = number;
        result = new ArrayList<>();
        while (numberCopy > 1) {
            PrimeGenerator primeGenerator = new PrimeGenerator();
            while (primeGenerator.hasNext()) {
                long prime = primeGenerator.nextLong();
                if (numberCopy % prime == 0) {
                    result.add(prime);
                    numberCopy /= prime;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Problem 3";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PrimeGenerator implements PrimitiveIterator.OfLong {
    private final static LongNode HEAD_NODE = new LongNode(2);

    private LongNode lastNode = HEAD_NODE;
    private long current = 2;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long nextLong() {
        if (lastNode.value == current) {
            if (lastNode.next != null) {
                long old = lastNode.value;
                lastNode = lastNode.next;
                current = lastNode.value;
                return old;
            }
            return current++;
        }
        while (true) {
            if (isPrime(current)) {
                appendNode(current);
                return current++;
            }
            current++;
        }
    }

    private boolean isPrime(final long number) {        
        LongNode prime = HEAD_NODE;
        while (prime != null && prime.value <= number) {
            if (number % prime.value == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            prime = prime.next;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void appendNode(final long value) {
        LongNode newNode = new LongNode(value);
        couple(lastNode, newNode);
        lastNode = newNode;
    }

    private void couple(final LongNode first, final LongNode second) {
        first.next = second;
        second.previous = first;
    } 

    private static class LongNode {
        public final long value;

        public LongNode previous;
        public LongNode next;

        public LongNode(final long value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static LongStream infiniteStream() {
        return StreamSupport.longStream(
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new PrimeGenerator(), Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE), false
        );
    }
}
```

Java 8 remarks:

- I've not used the `PrimeGenerator.infiniteStream()` in this answer, so no need to consider it.
- `ProjectEuler` class is just given for convenience.
- `PrimiteIterator.OfLong` is a primitive wrapper for Java 7 equivalent `Iterator<Long>`.

The idea I've used for this exercise was that I need a list of prime numbers. And everytime the original number modulo that prime was zero, I would add a factor to the list and divide the number by that prime.

Other remark on the speed, which I think is pretty interesting, I also ran code that sums up the first million prime numbers.

- When properly benchmarking, with 10000 warmups and 10000 real tests, the time was averaged 7.5ms.
- However with just one real test, it is still running after a considerate amount of time, at least an hour I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, your iterator is two iterators - one for the known primes (from previous 'warmups'), and one for unknown primes. Your known prime iterator's choice of implementation looks a bit cumbersome - you could have used a simple list of `Long`, and iterate over it:

```
private final static List<Long> KNOWN_PRIMES = new LinkedList<Long>();

private Iterator<Long> knownPrimeIterator = KNOWN_PRIMES.iterator();
private long lastResult = 1;

public long nextLong() {
    if (knownPrimeIterator != null && knownPrimeIterator.hasNext()) {
        lastResult = knownPrimeIterator.next().toLong();
    } else {
        knownPrimeIterator = null;
        lastResult = findNextPrime(lastResult+1);
        KNOWN_PRIMES.add(new Long(lastResult));
    }
    return lastResult;
}

private long findNextPrime(long startFrom) {
    // whatever here...
}
```

Regarding your benchmark, I believe that 'warming up' is a little like cheating... you are caching the results in your static array. If you wanted to have a high-performant solution, you could have pre-calculated the first 1,000,000 primes, saved them to a file, and read them at the beginning of the procedure... :P

Answer (score 6):

Some general observations.

- I agree with Uri that your use of the custom Linked-List is cumbersome. It also leads you to have redundant code, like you have an unused 'previous' node... Uri is right to syggest a List for this, but I would recommend an ArrayList as it will be faster (because it will use half the memory as it has half the number of Objects).... actually, like most times, I would prefer the use of an array of `long[]` with a `size` parameter to track how large it is, and then resize as needed. That will use about 10% of the memory of the same data in the LinkedList, and about 20% of the data in your LinkNode system. Despite what many people believe, Java performance in many ways is related to the memory footprint. Smaller data is faster.
- Your class is not thread-safe. This is a problem for using with Java8. If your PrimeGenerator is linked to a parallel Lambda then you will be in trouble. in particular, the `private final static LongNode HEAD_NODE = new LongNode(2);` is going to mean that all threads will try to modify the same linked structure.
- I am aware that you have changed the problem from being 'find the largest' to 'find them all', but, you should consider a system where you start from the highest prime that could possibly be a factor (`Math.sqrt(value)`) and work backwards. This will save a lot of computation:

  ```
  while (numberCopy > 1) {
      long root = (long)Math.sqrt(numberCopy);
      for (long prime : PrimesGenerator.descendingFrom(root)) {
          if (numberCopy % prime == 0) {
              numberCopy /= prime;
              factors.add(prime);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

A few comments:

- I agree that using a custom implementation of a LinkedList without a need to is a bad practice.
- Public mutable fields are bad.
- It is considered pedantic to add final to arguments.
- I don't like your method of generating primes. You check if a number is prime by iterating over all smaller primes. Two possible improvements would be to iterate only over primes in range [1, \sqrt{x}], or to use a fancy primality test like Miller-Rabin. But a faster and easier approach would be to use [Seive of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to generate primes.